# jquery error validation count not detecting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently working on jquery validator I have two panel one is Info and other one is major if the user click next button the error message was showing you have two fields missing this was perfectly fine but if the user select from undergraduate to post graduate radio button  and if the user select the value from major drop down the error count was not reducing. But if i select the value from undergraduate (major drop down) the count was reducing perfectly I have tried the below code where the drop down is selected.

Kindly help me I a struggling below is the fiddle link which i tried

```
$(".basicForm").validate().element(".slt_major");
```

the rest of the code i have updated in fiddle link kindly please check

Here is my [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/dyxdh9mw/)

Any suggestion please

Thanks in advance

Comment: @any suggestion for the above question\

Comment: guys kindly please help me on the above question